# Check if any of the strings of a list appears on a bigger string

Tags: python, loops

I have a list of strings. I would like to check if any of the strings of that list appears on a bigger document saved on a string var.

I know this can easily be done with a loop, but I will be doing this operation so many times (and another loops apart of this) so I was wondering if there is any more efficient way to do it instead of a for loop.

My approach is this one:

```
main_words = ... # List of words I want to check
tweet = ... # String containing the text I want to check for word appearance

for word in main_words:
    if word in tweet:
        .......
```

Comment: you can mention your approach ( code )

Comment: `if 'string' in 'biggeer string list ':'bigger string list'.count(string)`

Comment: @lazarus Sorry, I just added what I had on mind

Comment: The problem isn't the loop it is your data structures. Use a set

Comment: I'm not clear on the output you want.  Your wording suggests a simple Boolean result, but the discussion focuses on returning all such words.  Please clarify.  You truncated code example fails to specify the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sets to get this information:

```
text = """I have a list of strings. I would like to check if any of the strings of 
that list appears on a bigger document saved on a string var.

I know this can easily be done with a loop, but I will be doing this operation so 
many times (and another loops apart of this) so I was wondering if there is any
more efficient way to do it instead of a for loop."""

words = set(["would","this","do","if","supercalifragelisticexpialigetic"])

text_words = text.split()

# show all that are in it
print(words.intersection(text_words))   # words & set(text_words)
# show all that are not in it
print(words.difference(text_words))     # words - set(text_words)
```

Output:

```
set(['this', 'do', 'would', 'if'])               # words & set(text_words)
set(['supercalifragelisticexpialigetic'])        # words - set(text_words)
```

---

To get the counts as well:

```
from collections import Counter

counted = Counter(text_words)

for w in words:
    print(w, counted.get(w))
```

Output:

```
do 1
would 1
supercalifragelisticexpialigetic None
if 2
this 2
```